# How to extract information from Tweepy ResultSet

Tags: python, tweepy

How do I interact with the Tweepy Result set? How can I extract information? It kinda looks like a list or a dictionary, but I'm having trouble extracting specific elements of it.

```
import tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

print(type(api.favorites('twitter')))
Out[1]: <class 'tweepy.models.ResultSet'>

print(api.favorites('twitter'))
Out[2]: Status(favorited=False, source='Twitter for iPhone', in_reply_to_status_id=None, coordinates=None, text='Starting the Twitter chat now. https://t.co[...]
```

I've never dealt with an object like ResultSet before, so I'm not sure how I can extract information from it. I noticed that it works a bit like a list, in that I can get a specific tweet from the list like this:

```
print(api.favorites('twitter')[1])
```

But I cant get embedded elements like this:

```
print(api.favorites('twitter')[1][0])
Out[3]: TypeError: 'Status' object does not support indexing
```

or like this:

```
print(api.favorites('twitter')[1]['favorited'])
Out[4]: TypeError: 'Status' object is not subscriptable
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tweepy.ResultSet` is a [subclass of a Python's `list`](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/models.py#L10):

```
class ResultSet(list):
    """A list like object that holds results from a Twitter API query."""
```

The elements in the `ResultSet` can be of different types - statuses, users, relations etc.

Every element in your particular `ResultSet` is a [`Status` instance](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/models.py#L73), which allows the attribute access (via *dot notation*) to the twitter status properties:

```
result_set = api.favorites('twitter')
status = result_set[0]
print(status.favorited)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Is there a way to find all the elements of the object that I can reference with the dot notation? Currently, I'm just looking through the printed output and taking note, but I figure there's got to be a better way.

Comment: @Nate sure, I think the full underlying JSON object is available at `status._json`..

Comment: Thanks again @alecxe. For anyone looking for a quick answer: status._json.keys()

Answer (score 0):

Here i displayed the `resultset` using `for` loop. And inside for loop, use the same way as @alecxe mentioned to access each object property

```
# For ex, GET users/lookup API call returns resultset
users = api.lookup_users(screen_names=['StackOverflow,StackExchange'])
# get the length of user and @alecxe mentions
for i in range(len(users)):
    print 'Name - ' + users[i].name
    print 'Bio - ' + users[i].description
    print 'Location - ' + users[i].location
    print 'Joined at - ' + str(users[i].created_at)
    print 'User ID - ' + users[i].id_str
    print ''
```

**Output:**

```
Name - TechCrunch
Bio - Breaking technology news, analysis, and opinions from TechCrunch. Home to Disrupt, TC Sessions, and Startup Battlefield. Got a tip? tips@techcrunch.com
Location - San Francisco, CA
Joined at - 2007-03-07 01:27:09
User ID - 816653

Name - Piwik Analytics
Bio - Piwik is the leading open analytics platform (Web+Mobile). An open alternative to Google Analytics. Privacy is built-in. Tweet about Piwik if you love it!
Location - Planet Earth
Joined at - 2009-06-22 23:47:00
User ID - 49813707
```